# Following countdown timer

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

Is there a way to create a countdown timer that continues to countdown where it is left off when the user transferred to another page?

For example,

- On page 1 the user clicks on the link which takes them to page 2.
- The countdown timer on page 1 is XX:YY
- Page two loads and the countdown is XX:YY and continues from there...

Comment: Yes, look into the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it depends how are you developing you application.

If you are working on [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), it'll be easy. Since your JS state won't change while user is navigating on your page, you just need to put the countdown on a global variable/singleton and update on it (remember that it could break if user open a new tab or refresh the page).

You also could keep this state on a [SharedWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) and share this information between many tabs, and persist this data using [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API).